# No inicia tomcat 9

Tags: netbeans, apache, tomcat, configuración

Instale apache tomcat 9 para utilizarlo como servidor en una aplicación web que voy a desarrollar en netbeans 14.

Al iniciar el servidor me pide la autenticación de usuario, al ingresar las credenciales no me permite avanzar. Ya miré el user.xml de tomcat y verifiqué los usuarios que en algún momento agregué. Qué más podría hacer?
[image: servidor en netbeans]

[image: archivo user.xml]

Comment: Por qué tienes dos usuarios admin en el archivo de configuración? Y lo que es más importante: ¿realmente necesitas tener usuarios admin en ese tomcat? El error en netbeans realmente dice que el puerto 8080 ya está en uso, tienes otro tomcat por ahí andando...

Comment: Muchas gracias. ya resolví el problema. comenté los usuarios del archivo de configuración y volví a agregar el servidor a netbeans.